# Not able to get Linux disk space using SNMP

Tags: snmp

I am enabled the disk monitoring service in /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf using "disk /". But when i ran snmpwalk i didn't get any informations related to disks space. Did i miss anything.

Any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: I got the answer, I haven't enable all the oids in snmpd.conf. now iam getting disk usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, I haven't enable all the oids in snmpd.conf. now iam getting disk usage.